# Can I use Commit or Rollback in exception block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, commit, rollback

Is it possible to use `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` inside an `EXCEPTION` block?

I know this may not be a good practice because the user might want to rollback after an exception occurred and if I use a `COMMIT` there that won't be possible.
However my application won't allow any kind of rollback and everything is committed, either being a success or a failure.

Comment: Yes, it is. As you said, it is not recommended though

Comment: `COMMIT` Especially  for each transaction is not advisable. You can use one `COMMIT` just before the `END;` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use either `COMMIT`or `ROLLBACK` in an `EXCEPTION` block.  `ROLLBACK` especially when combined with a save point, is much more common than `COMMIT`.  `COMMIT` certainly is not expected in most apps.  I certainly wouldn't use a `COMMIT` in an `EXCEPTION` block anywhere except at the outermost layer of code.